# how to add a custom widget to Qt 4.8.6

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to figure out how to add a custom widget to Qt Designer. So far I've been unsuccessful. Very new to Qt. I'm running Qt 4.8.6. I know there is a newer version but due to project constraints I have to stick with this one. Essentially  I'm need to add a hex spin box, i.e. a spinbox that counts in hex rather than in decimals. I even found [code that implements it](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.18.1.41/1/). It does explain [how to integrate it into Qt Designer](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.18.1.44/1/), however it is explained for version 3. Can someone offer assistance?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It's all documented, and there are examples in the documentation that comes with Qt 4.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [creating designer widgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-creating-custom-widgets.html) and [using them](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html), but briefly:

- Subclass [`QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesignercustomwidgetinterface.html) to create your custom designer plugin for your custom widget
- Build and install your designer plugin
- Tell designer about your plugin location, or just make sure it's installed to `$QTDIR/plugins/designer`

There's also [an example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-designer-customwidgetplugin-example.html) to follow.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html) is a documentation. At short, you just add any widget (e.g. `QSpinBox` to draw it nice in the Designer) to your form and convert it to the needed one.

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom widget to Qt designer simply follow the steps:

1. In Qt designer create a new widget File->New->Widget.
2. Add your UI etc for this widget and save it->->MyWidget.ui
3. Create a class "MyWidgetHandler" to handle this widget in a MyWidgetHandler.h & cpp
4. In your MainWindow/Dialog wherever you want to display this widget add a "Widget" from the "Containers" section of the designer.

   [image]
5. Now right-click the "Widget" container you just added and click "Promote to..."
6. This should open a dialog. You can select here the base class to inherit properties in your case QComboBox or just select the QWidget class.
7. Next enter the full class name i.e with namespaces eg: "blah::MyWidgetHandler"
8. In the Header file section simply add the path to the header file for this class. This should be a resolvable path. Eg: "UI/MyWidgetHandler.h" or "C:/UI/MyWidgetHandler.h"
9. Now click "Promote" and save your MainWindow.ui
10. The Property Editor should now show your custom class type eg: blah::MyWidgetHandler. and the properties from the base class you selected.
11. Don't forget to setup the UI in your handler class and include header in the Mainwindow handler.

Cheers !!!

Comment: What if my UI is exactly the same as for QSpinBox? How do I go about it?

Comment: In that case:  
 - skip step 1 and 2  
 - in step 3 myWidgetHandler should derive from QSpinBox.  
 - you can override the QSpinbox methods as you wish in the implementation.  
 - remember in the main ui handler this custom class can be called by the object name see attached image in point 10 in the original answer.